# Why is react-beautiful-dnd jolting on drag-n-drop in a simple list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd

You'll notice in this gif that when I drag an item, the surrounding items don't get fully out of the way, only about *half* out of the way. Then when I drop, everything jolts and snaps into place. Why is that? I have just a basic hello world implementation.

[image]

Notice on this second image that when I drag down, the items below are only halfway moved to position pretty much, and then the ugly jolt. How do I make it smooth and so everything moves out of the way into the correct position?

[image]

Here's basically what I have:

```
const getListStyle = (isDraggingOver) => ({
  opacity: isDraggingOver ? 0.7 : 1,
});

<Droppable droppableId="droppable">
  {(provided, snapshot) => (
    <div
      {...provided.droppableProps}
      ref={provided.innerRef}
      style={getListStyle(snapshot.isDraggingOver)}
    >
      {items.map((item, i) => (
        <MyItem
          key={item.id}
          data={item}
          index={i}
        />
      ))}
      {provided.placeholder}
    </div>
  )}
</Droppable>

const MyItem = ({ data, index }) => {
  return (
    <Draggable key={data.id} draggableId={data.id} index={index}>
      {provided => (
        <section
          {...provided.draggableProps}
        >
          <LinesIcon
            className={styles.dragHandle}
            ref={provided.innerRef}
            {...provided.dragHandleProps}
          />
          <div>content...</div>
        </section>
      )}
    </Draggable>
  )
}
```

I would like for the items to move completely out of the way, to fill their empty spot properly, not halfway. And to get rid of the jolting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, it was because I was putting the ref on the wrong draggable item, I needed it on the outermost parent not a nested item (the drag handle).